# How to append Hexa decimal value in the string c++?

Tags: c++, string, hex, c++14

I was trying to append the Hexa decimal value `'F'` to the string which contains some data.

Example:

```
std:string myString = "1234567";
```

Now I want to append the Hex Value `'F'` in the end of the string.

The user of the string could able to identify the last value is HEXDecimal. is there a way to store the Hex value in string ?

Expected output: `myString as 1234567F.`

Any idea how to do it in c++ ?

Comment: `myString += 'F';` seems too obvious, so what really is your question?

Comment: @KenY-N: I think he wants to append 'F' which is stored in a `int` variable. Let's see if he clarifies further.

Comment: Hi, my question is to append any HEX value in to the string. I know we can simply append it using the '+'. but it can be later identified as HEX while decoding.

Comment: example : In the data, '1234567' is numeric. when user reads the final character 'F' if anyone can by default understand it is Hex

Comment: @SheikCode: So you want it to be identified as hex only if it contains any letter from A to F?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply `myString += 'F'` and your output will be as desired. If you would like to convert your string to an `int` and then print it in actual hex, you can do something like this:

```
std::string myString = "1234567";
int myInt = std::stoi(myString);
std::cout << std::hex << myInt;

>>> 12d687
```